# Can't get Base64.decodeBase64 to work (Commons codec)

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons-codec

```
String encode = Base64.encodeBase64String("Hello".getBytes());
System.out.println(encode);
byte[] decode = Base64.decodeBase64(encode);
System.out.println(decode.toString());
```

I can't tell whats wrong here.  I've tried every possible combination there is.  Set the charset, toString, no toString.  The encode works perfectly.  I can throw that number into a web decoder and get the right value every time.  Just can't get this to work.

Output:

```
 run:
SGVsbG8= (encode)

[B@1fb8ee3  (decode)
```

I can make it work if I use a for loop and manually add the characters to a string. But I thought toString did that for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem is how you're converting the byte array to a string.

Try this instead:

```
System.out.println(new String(decode));
```

*However*, it's generally a bad idea to use the overloads of `String.getBytes()` or `new String(byte[])` which don't specify a character encoding. They use the platform default encoding, which immediately means your code isn't portable - or at least, your data isn't. I suggest you use a common encoding such as UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I guess I wasn't thinking about the toString on an array.  Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` on an array doesn't do what you're expecting... it's just the default `toString()` implementation from `Object`, which returns a string based on the hashcode of the object. Try `new String(decode)`.